# javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider cannot be resolved

Tags: spring-mvc

The type javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

```
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);// getting error at this line

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
```

Comment: Is the necessary jar present in the classpath?

Comment: Yes, i added but no result

Comment: what version hibernate using? use `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` is the replacement.

Comment: i am using hibernate 4.0

Answer (score 1):

If you still have this problem the PersistenceProvider class is found in hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar for Hibernate 4.0.1.Final. Maven would resolve the dependency automatically for you.